# How do we assign value to variable to later use in LabView?

Tags: variables, labview

I'm reading dynamic data from a sensor in LabView and I'm trying store the initial value for the first position of the device to compare and use for the zero value.

I've tried to create an array and store it as an element inside of **case-structure** which is activated via boolean button but for some reasons the output of case-structure can't be used.
I've seen people successfully using the shift registers but in LabView 2017 it seems I only can use **feedback node**. What's the easiest way to implement such a structure?

Expected result would be assigning a single data-point read from sensor to a variable. I'm using LabView 2017.

**Note**:It seems in **LabView 2017** using shift register by right click on wire is **not** the option anymore !

**Update**: below is the snippet of program:
[image: img]

Comment: _"in LabView 2017 I only can use feedback node"_ -- Please add why. LabVIEW 2017 **has** shift registers, so what is the constraint?

Comment: @Joe It has for while loop but it seems it has not for **case structure**

Comment: How does your program do multiple reads from the sensor without a loop? Do you place a sequence of read blocks? Can you add a block diagram snippet?

Comment: @Joe I have a while loop for whole structure but the thing is I want to lead the first 10 data on command that's why I was thinking of adding another case structure inside and furthermore I don't know how to read the first 10 data registered in my array because it's constantly updating.

Comment: @Mario Without code to examine, this is an exercise in futility. Please attach a snippet of code or the whole vi so we can know, without guessing, what your issue is.

Comment: @Dave_St I just updated by snippet of program

Comment: @JoeFriedrichsen I added the snippet of program.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a wire on the tunnel of a looping structure, you can right click, and change the tunnel mode to Shift Register. So I'm not sure what you mean by saying you can only use feedback nodes.

[image: Right click on tunnel]

Comment: I knew about that and I was using that in my previous version of my LabView but in 2017 version adding shift register is not option when I used right click on wire!! may i ask you what's your LabView version?

Comment: I originally deleted my post because I realized you were talking about dynamic data, and since I never really use dynamic data, I wasn't sure if that was causing the problem.

But now that I see your snippet, I'm not sure, since you're not trying to use the dynamic data. And since it's a While loop, you absolutely can use a shift register.

When you say you're trying to average out the first three seconds for stabilization, is it really just the first three seconds? Or is a running average with a 3 second window?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a while loop in which you take your measurements. You can use its loop iteration terminal to determine whether you are measuring your initial (or first ten) measurements. You can then store these values in a shift register to be available for future measurements to use. You just need to stop updating your shift register once you have acquired your initial (or first ten) measurements.

The VI snippet below shows a way of achieving this. The case structure has only one other not visible state that is the default case where the first 10 readings array is simply wired straight through and so unchanged.

Without further details, it is difficult to say whether this does answer your question. If it doesn't then I would suggest posting a snippet of your code or at least enough to show how it is currently working.

[image]

Comment: I have added the snippet as requested. Your solution did not work for me but gave me different ideas to try. Now I am just storing the values in a file to read it later but this is not efficient. So If you have any suggestions I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the elapsed time function? This way you can create an array and get the mean for the first x seconds. 
[image]

Alternatively, you can use a state machine in which you create a separate 'calibration' state where you perform this action.
The state machine also allows you to initialize and stop the hardware properly. Keeps your code more readable and scalable.

Best regards,
San